# Least-norm problem with equality constraints

Tags: optimization, inverse-problems

My inverse problems teacher said that the least norm problem can be resolved using equality constraints. How is that?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1865950/339790) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2248839/339790).